# Guardar todas las coincidencias de un grupo en Regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix, perl, ksh

Consideremos el siguiente grupo:

```
([0-9 ]+)+
```

Capturo coincidencias que contenga números y espacios, en la siguiente cadena por ejemplo:

```
123  , 2133132, 31331, 22222222, 23......
```

se capturaría " 23", la última coincidencia, pero lo que yo quiero es poder guardar todas las coincidencias,en este caso hubieran sido cinco.

Estoy intentando usando perl, con lo que tendría algo así:

```
echo "123  , 2133132, 31331, 22222222, 23....." | perl -pe "s/([0-9 ]+)+/\1/g"
```

Y pues lo mismo, sólo el último.

Nota: Estoy trabajando en shell script, concrétamente ksh en Hp ux.

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje/herramienta?

Comment: Estoy usando ksh en HP UX.

Comment: No tengo idea de ksh, pero te puedo decir que al repetir un grupo (paréntesis), sólo se capturará la última coincidencia. Para lo que estás buscando, hay que buscar las coincidencias de `[0-9 ]+` y mostrar el resultado de todas las coincidencias globales. En muchos lenguajes es con el modificador `/g`, en grep es con `-o`.

Comment: ¿Sabes cómo sería con perl? He actualizado la pregunta.

Comment: En ksh las cosas son más complicadas, realmente un servidor HP UX es algo poco práctico para estas cosas. Lo que no me queda claro es qué quieres hacer con las coincidencias. ¿Vas a hacer un bucle y quieres hacer algo sobre cada valor? Si nos explicas tu objetivo final podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Estoy usando el comando vmstat y mi intención es coger ciertos valores de la salida. Puedo coger los valores que quiero haciendo coincidir un patrón, pero el comando resulta bastante extenso y no me gusta, quería algo más fino.

Comment: manduina: ¿Has consultado `man vmstat`? Hay multitud de parámetros para configurar la salida para que sea lo más personalizada posible. Utilizar expresiones regulares para la salida de un comando debería ser la última opción tras hacer un buen barrido a las opciones que este te proporciona. Más que nada porque las opciones se suelen mantener, pero el formato puede cambiar y, por ende, romper tu solución con regexs.

Comment: @fedorqui de acuerdo contigo. En este caso lo reduje al máximo y luego apliqué un par de greps para limpiar los datos extras.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se repite un grupo, se captura únicamente el último texto que coincidió. Para mostrar cada resultado, se necesita efectuar múltiples coincidencias.

Para que se busquen todas las coincidencias, se debe utilizar el modificador `/g` (GLOBAL). No es necesario usar grupos, basta con el resultado de la coincidencia global.

En Perl:

```pl
my $texto = "123  , 2133132, 31331, 22222222, 23.....";

my @matches = $texto =~ /[\d ]+/g;

print "@matches\n";
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/CPGDU3637

O, desde línea de comando:

```
$ echo -ne '123  , 2133132, 31331, 22222222, 23.....' | perl -wnE'say for /[\d ]+/g'
```

Comment: con `echo` a secas ya tienes el `\n`. Y si quieres utilizar `\n` y demás, usa `printf`, [algo más recomendado](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/40596) y sobre todo en entornos tan particulares como ksh + HPUX.

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias. Igual era simplemente un ejemplo porque amplió la pregunta a Perl, para explicar que era la coincidencia global y no la repetición de un grupo... Pero sólo hasta ver tu respuesta directa a la pregunta... Este es tu campo, yo apenas observo

Comment: Este comando último va muy bien en Bash, pero en Ksh da errores. Perl parece ser algo distinto aquí. Igual creo que la idea está bien. Le voy a dar un par de vueltas de paso que aprendo Perl.

Comment: @manduinca hasta acá puedo llegar. Realmente no tengo idea de ksh como te mencioné en mi primer comentario. Sí creo que sirve para explicar que no se debe repetir un grupo en la forma `(expresión)+`, sino buscar todos los resultados del regex. Pero esperemos a la respuesta de alguien que sepa de ksh, esto fue sólo para guiarte mientras tanto ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hay que prestar atención a las comillas simples, que rodean al miniprograma Perl:

```
echo "123  , 2133132, 31331, 22222222, 23....." | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while /([0-9]+)/g'
```